# run initializer before ember unit test

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data

I want to write a unit test for a route's method.

**routes/tickets**

```
addTicketUserAssoc(ticket, ticketUserAssoc) {
  let copy = ticketUserAssoc.copy();
  copy.set('ticket', ticket);
  ticketUserAssoc.reset();
},
```

It uses `copy` and `reset` on an ember-data record. They are methods which   are added during initialization.

**initializers/model**

```
export default {
  name: 'model',
  initialize: function() {
    if (alreadyRun) {
        return;
    } else {
        alreadyRun = true;
    }

    DS.Model.reopen(isValidated, {
      copy: function(options){
        // some code ...
      },
      reset() {
        // some code ...  
      }
    });
  }
};
```

If I try to import the initializer to the unit test, it does not even appears on the qunit's module list.

**Solution**
I ended up doing this:

```
moduleFor('route:tickets', 'Unit | Route | tickets', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: [
    // ...
  ],
  beforeEach() {
    Ember.run(function() {
      application = Ember.Application.create();
      application.deferReadiness();
    });
  }
});

test('assign ticket', function(assert){
  let route = this.subject();
  let store = route.get('store');
  ModelInitializer.initialize(application);
  // ...
})
```

Comment: if you use both route/initializer - it should be integration / acceptance test. Unit test - test just unit ( route in your case ), and have no knowledge about initializer

Comment: Separate the `DS.Model.reopen ...` code in a utility class. Use it from both  test code and initializer.